# Does Ubuntu on Nexus 7 support the GPS hardware?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, gps

If I install Ubuntu onto my Nexus 7 via [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) will I still be able to use GPS and Google Maps?

Comment: Most issues are covered in: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/KnownIssues

Comment: Otherwise, add your question to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7

Comment: @david6: That link is for bug reports, not for questions.

Comment: @Flimm, I meant: "*You may need to raise this as a bug.*"

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that currently there is not support for the onboard GPS. Developers are still working on getting functionality out of the firmware for broadcom wifi and bluetooth.